# Trouble piping output from python script

Tags: python, unix, grep, pipe, command-line-interface

I am having trouble getting the output from a python script, that I didn't write, redirected to grep. Below are my experiments including the base cases. "myPythonCmd" is long running and streams to stdout.

Any suggestions?

---

```
/myPythonCmd.py arg1 arg2
```

Outputs both stderr and stdout to the screen

```
/myPythonCmd.py arg1 arg2 2>/dev/null
```

Outputs just stdout to the screen

```
/myPythonCmd.py arg1 arg2 2>/dev/null > outputfile
```

Outputs nothing to the screen, but writes stdout to outputfile

```
/myPythonCmd.py arg1 arg2 2>/dev/null | grep searchTerm
```

Outputs NOTHING even though I know searchTerm is present.

```
/myPythonCmd.py arg1 arg2 2>/dev/null | grep --line-buffered searchTerm
```

Outputs NOTHING even though I know searchTerm is present.

Comment: could it be that searchTerm is displayed in stderr? That is, what if you say `/myPythonCmd.py arg1 arg2  | grep searchTerm`?

Comment: Weird. I don't suppose you could post a [mcve] that illustrates this problem? Is the stdout from the Python script plain ASCII, or does it contain Unicode or other special characters? Are you using Python 2 or Python 3? Does supplying the `-u` option (unbuffered) to Python make a difference; I don't expect it to, but I guess it's worth trying.

Comment: Thanks for asking, but nope. the searchTerm appears in on screen and in the outputfile when stderr is piped to /dev/null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

python's -u option is what was needed. Thanks @PM_2Ring

```
python -u myPythonCmd.py arg1 arg2 2>/dev/null | grep searchTerm
```